# Too many Activity in the stack make the app pretty slow

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Recently I created a social app. I didn't use fragment and the project is almost finished. I have several Activities like UserProfile, Followers, Followings activity.

Normally it's just working fine. But if user click UserA UserProfile activity -> and then click A's Followers -> select UserB Userprofile activity -> click B's followers activity -> select UserC Userprofile activity....

In this loop, the app would get pretty slower because it opened too many activities at same time and the back stack hold all of them.

I just wonder if there's any optimization I could do for this situation? Because UserProfile activity layout would always same except the user information content. Is that possible to use Fragment for each activity, even though different activities would show up in sequence one by one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should architect this in a different way. You should only ever have one `UserProfileActivity` in the stack. If you already have the `UserProfileActivity` for User A in the stack, and you want to show the `UserProfileActivity` for User B, just call `startActivity()` for `UserProfileActivity` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and pass some extras to indicate that the `Activity` should show User B. Use the same concept for all of your activities.

To make sure that the BACK button navigation works correctly, you will need to override `onBackPressed()` and figure out what `Activity` needs to be shown and with what data. Then call `startActivity()` and also set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and provide extras so the `Activity` will show the correct data.

To assist in keeping track of where you are in the navigation, you might want to create a stack of items that are stored in a `static` variable somewhere. Each item would indicate what `Activity` is being shown and with what data. Every time you launch a new `Activity`, you push a new item on to this stack, and every time the user presses the BACK key, you pop the top item off the stack and then look at the one underneath it to determine what `Activity` to start and what data to send in the extras.

With this scheme, the user can click around all day long and you will never have more than one instance of each `Activity`, but the user will still be able to navigate all the way back.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It looks very clean and smart. I would try to maintain a static stack to track the activity behavior.